# Why do preflight requests sometimes appear after the main request in Chrome DevTools network tab?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

My understanding of preflight requests is that they are just that - a request before the main request.

Often in the Chrome DevTools Network tab I see the preflight OPTIONS request appear after the main one.

Why is that?

Comment: I've often wondered this myself... I chalked it up to a weird timing issue, but it would be good to have a definitive answer...

Comment: It may be a bug in devtools UI. You can report it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the preflight (OPTIONS) request get listed after the actual (GET) request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75973978/why-does-the-preflight-options-request-get-listed-after-the-actual-get-reque)

Comment: @jub0bs it most certainly does. Thanks!